# How to set height of recyclerview programmatically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried,

```
recyclerview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100));
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try to set height like this,

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params=recyclerview.getLayoutParams();
params.height=100;
recyclerview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: That's the best possible solution on runtime, there is no other way I found to do a dynamic height change for recyclerview.

Answer (score 10):

Came across same question just now and although ajantha's solution works, I found a more simpler solution. If this still helps, great, glad to pay it forward.

```
recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's too late but I have a better solution.
`recyclerView.getLayoutParams().height` will give you `null pointer` when you create a new `recycler view` programmatically. Here is a proper way of doing it.

```
RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  recyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Keep in mind that the first param is `width` while the second is `height`.

Comment: ideal way to set the width and height on any Android views at runtime